# callback function in sails.JS v1

Tags: node.js, function, async-await, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am new to sailsJS.
I want to add record in collection named skills.

I have refered this document of sails js https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create

I have request as :

```
{
    "skillName": "tblPreffered PartneersTest",
    "active": "true"
}
```

my function is :

```
 FnCreate :  function(req,res){
    var Data = await Skills.create(req.body).exec().fetch();
    console.log('data  is :'+JSON.stringify(Data)); 
    res.send({
        status      : true,
        statusCode  : 200,
        message     : "New Skill added",
        responce    : Data,     
    })
  }
```

now when i run, it says error as :

```
var Data = await Skills.create(req.body).exec().fetch();
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

can any one help me what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You need you use `async` keyword :

```
FnCreate :  async function(req,res){
                  var Data = await Skills.create(req.body).fetch();
                  console.log('data  is :'+JSON.stringify(Data)); 
                  res.send({
                  status      : true,
                  statusCode  : 200,
                  message     : "New Skill added",
                  responce    : Data,     
            })
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response @hamza ,  it i tried your solution but its says .
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token function ."

Comment: what version of sails are you using ?

Comment: Using sails V1.0

Comment: Try to write your handler like this :  async FnCreate(req,res) { ... }

Comment: Thanks for your support @hamza, I was using older version of NodeJS .
While async/await  doesn't work with older version  than node 7.6.
I have  perfomed two steps to resolve it as :
1) I installed latest version of node .
2) as suggested by you , removed ".exec()" 

and it works. thanks